# Replacement for a 32-bit third-party library while porting to 64-bit

Tags: c++, adobe, activex, 32bit-64bit, ocx

I am working on porting my 32-bit Control to 64-bit. The problem is that it uses ATM (Adobe Type Manager) library 32-bit version and I am not sure there is a 64-bit version of this library. What are my options? Any ideas about ATM source code?

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is no problem with running code designed for 32-bit processors on 64-bit machines. Try just using this one.